# Is there any plugin which expands image such as thumbnail image to some large size?

Tags: php, jquery, css, image, jquery-plugins

I have search result which includes images. When the user hover over the image the image should expand somewhat large size like we see on bing image search. Is there any Plugin for that. Please help. Any Suggestion will be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

http://cssglobe.com/post/1695/easiest-tooltip-and-image-preview-using-jquery

http://james.padolsey.com/javascript/new-jquery-plugin-imgpreview/

Try those.

Comment: I need the image which expands while hover should be automatically generated i.e it should not take another image as parameter

Answer (score 1):

What about this [zoomimage](http://www.eyecon.ro/zoomimage/) plugin? It looks like it provides callbacks that you could use to change it from click to mouseover

---

It's not a plugin, but I found [this tutorial](http://www.sohtanaka.com/web-design/fancy-thumbnail-hover-effect-w-jquery/) that might help you.

Comment: I just updated my answer with a tutorial I found that might do what you want.